# What documents are needed to take a child to the UK?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, children, minors

I am  Brazilian taking my daughter to visit UK. She is on an adoption process in Brazil so I have her temporary guardianship until the adoption goes through.

I have the judge's permit to take her to the UK but do I need to have these documents translated?

Answer (score 7):

You want to take a child across international borders and in to the UK.

We have to be mindful that in addition to the basic visitor rules expressed in [Appendix v](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules), that Parliament has also instructed the Border Force to be alert and act as preliminary enforcers for the [Children Act 2004](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2004/31). This is an additional responsibility over and above protecting our borders and invites additional scrutiny.  The Border Force has taken this responsibility seriously and can be quite aggressive about it.

People who are unaware of this responsibility can find the extra diligence invasive and even insulting.  Brits travelling with children can become especially upset; they can get angry and [post hot takes on the net](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53975/children-with-a-different-surname-to-parent-uk-citizen-uk-passport-control).

Your question...

> I have the judge's permit to take her to the UK but do I need to have
>   these documents translated?

This document should be

1. translated to English; and
2. have an [apostille affixed to it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostille_Convention).

Maybe they will ask for the apostille or they may require you to get one whilst in the UK. Or maybe they will trust you. I always advise people to play everything *strictly by the book* and avoid problems. You should also have an apostille of the child's birth certificate.  The child's maintenance and care during their visit **in the EEA** should be documented, they can get you for that also because some of their responsibilities are handed down from Brussels.

For more background, read ILPA's Fact Sheet: [Children: New Statutory Duty](http://www.ilpa.org.uk/data/resources/4657/09.08.1115.pdf).

---

Disclaimer: I am a member of ILPA.

---

Anecdote from the thread linked to above (posted by user47663)

> I have twice been questioned upon arriving back in Britain from
>   France, although both times was allowed through. My son (aged 8) and I
>   are both British, fair haired and look alike. Last time the passport
>   control officer simply asked him "Who is this lady?" and was satisfied
>   when he said Mummy. However I saw another mother and young daughter at
>   the booth next to me getting a considerably harder time, and indeed I
>   was less sympathetically treated the year before, until a supervisor
>   decided my son looked 'comfortable' with me. This year I am taking his
>   birth certificate, irritating though it is, especially as I had to
>   produce it to apply for his passport in the first place! I also
>   pointed out that I had not been advised that I should carry his birth
>   certificate when I received his passport, only when I arrived at
>   border control (which was a tad too late).