# Visa advice for minor person wishing to enter the UK unaccompanied

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, minors

My name is Tom and I am turning 18 in 6 months. I want to go to London in the first week of May but on my visa it's written only valid if accompanied by my mother. So my question is that if a get consent letter sign from my mother, can I go to England alone?

Comment: @Traveller I don't think this is a duplicate. The answer is probably the same (at least in theory - at least one answer to the other question suggests theory and principle might not correspond, I very much doubt that's the case in this scenario), but there's a big difference between the premises of the questions: "my mum will write a letter" vs. "my mum is already in the UK and will be waiting for me in the airport"

Answer (score 20):

I'm assuming that this is a [Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa).

No, you cannot make the trip alone with your current visa.

A letter from your mother doesn't help, because your visa conditions are set by the authority that issues the visa (in this case, that's the UK). Nobody else can remove those conditions.

UK visitor visas for people aged below 18 can be issued for [travelling alone or for travelling with an adult](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/if-youre-under-18). The application requirements are different and you can't convert the latter into the former.

The guidance on the linked page states that if you have a visa for travelling with an adult

> you’ll be refused entry to the UK if you arrive in the UK without them.

Comment: I think that the mother explicitly can be avoided however, with an adult friend and a letter from your guardian (mother) that he is in charge of you.

Comment: @Hobbamok Are you sure? The type of visa the OP has does not just say the OP will be traveling with some adult. It specifies the OP will be traveling with the OP's mother.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I supposed that he used mother here while it states "guardian" on the Visa itself, as that is the more common terminology. If it actually states mother then he'd have to apply for a new one (or get it changed if the UK allows that)

Comment: Also: this question might be answered here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51015/transiting-from-the-us-through-the-uk-on-a-child-visitor-visa
[it has US in the title but that's irrelevant], I didn't flag it as duplicate tho, because that questions mentions a specific type of visa, which you didn't specify here

Comment: @Hobbamok the guidance page I linked in the answer seems very clear to me - the visa is only valid if they're accompanied. The accompanying person doesn't have to be the parent, but the specific person must be named when applying for the visa. I see no reason to believe a letter written after the visa's already acquired can have any value. The other answer refers to a type of visa which no longer exists.

Comment: My comment might have been clearer if I had written "It specifies the OP will be traveling with a named person, in this case the OP's mother."

Comment: @Hobbamok accompanied UK visas do not list the relations. They list specific names and passport numbers of maximum 2 people whom the child is allowed to travel to the UK with. Regardless of the relation one of the named persons has to accompany the child. There are no exceptions to this answer, it stands true in every possible case. OP will have to apply for a new visa.

Answer (score 2):

A consent letter is not a solution, so you need to look for other ideas:

- Persuade your mother to accompany you, and spend the same amount of time in the UK. You do have to be together to travel to and from the UK, but, with her permission, you can do different things while you are there.
- Apply for an unaccompanied minor visa. It is probably too late to get the paperwork together and apply in time for a May trip, so it may need some delay. You would need someone in the UK who can house you and will be responsible for you during your trip. This would be appropriate if, for example, you are visiting a relative who lives in London.
- Delay your trip until you are eighteen, and apply for a simple standard visitor visa. The problem with this is that minors are presumed to be likely to return to where their parents or guardians live. As an adult, you have to independently convince the immigration authorities that you will leave the UK at the end of your trip. That can be very difficult for a young person who is not yet fully integrated into their home country economy and society.